# HtmlUnit: unable to get html code like in web page

Tags: java, htmlunit

I just want to get a string from the ipinfo.io site, but when parsing the page using HtmlUnit, the list is returned empty for some reason, although the element code on the site shows that it is not empty.
Why is this happening and how to fix it?

My java code:

```
LogFactory.getFactory().setAttribute("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");

        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.OFF);
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.commons.httpclient").setLevel(Level.OFF);

        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.EDGE);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setAppletEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setFetchPolyfillEnabled(true);
        webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
        final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("https://ipinfo.io/");
        HtmlForm form = page1.getForms().get(0);
        List<DomElement> elements = StreamSupport.stream(form.getChildElements().spliterator(), false).collect(Collectors.toList());
        HtmlTextInput textField = form.getInputByValue("");
        textField.setValueAttribute("8.8.4.4");
        HtmlPage page2 = elements.get(1).click();
        HtmlDivision div = (HtmlDivision) page2.getElementById("tryit-data");
        HtmlUnorderedList list = (HtmlUnorderedList) StreamSupport.stream(div.getChildElements().spliterator(), false).collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0);
        System.out.println(list.asXml());
```

this is what I get when i run the code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pEmc.png)

How it actually looks on the site
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/racuD.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have done some tests with you example. This will not work at the moment because some deficits of the current js support.

two reasons

- TypeError: redeclaration of formal parameter t. (https://cdn.ipinfo.io/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app-1b76d095f7792b77.js#1)
- missing ( before function parameters. (https://cdn.ipinfo.io/_next/static/chunks/8374-d56693eab3444afc.js#1)

Both log messages are pointing to some js constructs used in the page code that are not supported at the moment.
I have some plans to improve the support in the future.